# Problemas com a importação de bibliotecas

Tags: android, android-studio, biblioteca

Comecei a desenvolver para Android no meu trabalho e me pediram pra começar trocando algumas coisas simples de um projeto ja existente, que funciona e inclusive ja foi lançado(a versão que estou querendo testar). Porem eu não consigo roda-lo de jeito nenhum.

Me aconselharam a criar um projeto novo e passar tudo do antigo(que não é grandle-based) pra esse. Eu fiz isso e depois de algum esforço eu consegui importar as bibliotecas do facebook e do google nas dependencias do buid.grandle. Meu problema é com a biblioteca com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library que da os mesmos problemas que as outras antes de compilar, então eu uso o comando:

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library:2.1.1'
```

Aparece o erro:

> Warning:Packaging for dependency
>   com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library:2.1.1 is 'apklib' and is
>   not supported. Only 'aar' libraries are supported.

Acredito que só falta isso para minha aplicação rodar. Mas caso não funcione, teria alguma solução melhor pra eu conseguir fazer funcionar no Android Studio?

aqui está o código do meu buid.grandle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aevo.talk_talk"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.+'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library:2.1.1'

}
```

E o que eu quero importar:

```
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener;
```

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta dessa pergunta
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040558/is-it-possible-to-add-apklibs-to-dependencies-with-intellij

Answer (score 1):

O erro em questão informa que a biblioteca que você está tentando utilizar não possui uma versão AAR, que é o único formato suportado. Segundo o [Repositório Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh/library/2.1.1), a versão 2.1.1 só está disponível em formato APKLIB.

Devido à natureza do formato, você pode extrair o arquivo APKLIB e compila-lo como AAR, para então usar no projeto. [Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28637316/3237900) resposta do StackOverflow (em inglês) explica como fazê-lo.

Sugiro que pesquise também outras bibliotecas do tipo, pois esta parece estar desatualizada. Sites como o [Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com) reúnem diversas bibliotecas e projetos reutilizáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Para importar bibliotecas de forma mais simples no android studio recomendo clicar com o botão direito no diretório app (que fica na árvore do seu projeto), depois em Open Modues Settings. Na janela que abrir vá na guia Dependencies e clique no sinal de + no canto superior direito, depois library dependecy. Na caixa de pesquisa digite uma referência a sua biblioteca ex.(chrisbanes, já que ele tem muitas outras bibliotecas). Na lista que aparecer selecione a que vc precisa e clique em ok... Pode demorar um pouco até ele importar a library, por que ae ele baixa e instala tudo pra vc automaticamente. Depois é só usar o import da biblioteca no seu projeto.